# jsf primefaces validation message repeatedly displayed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, message

I am using primefaces 3.3.

I've got a dataTable looking like this:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{someBean.items}" var="item" ..>
  <p:column>
    <p:inputText id="someInputText" validation="#{someBean.someValidator}">
  </p:column>
  ..
</p:dataTable>
```

The validator is standard:

```
public void someValidator (FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

  if(someCondition) {
    throw new ValidatorException(
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "error: ", "validation failed"));
  }
```

The problem I have is that if there are several items in the dataTable and if validation of inputText component "someInputText" fails just for one of the items then the validation error message is shown for every item.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Do you have a <p:messages> component on your page to catch global errors? And/or do you have <p:message> for each input field? Or is your code just like it is above with no <p:messages> and no <p:message> components?

Answer (score 3):

Use the for attribute of the p:message like this:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{someBean.items}" var="item">
  <p:column>
    <p:inputText id="someInputText1" validator="#{someBean.someValidator}" value="item.name">
    <p:message id="someInputText1Msg" for="someInputText1" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column>
    <p:inputText id="someInputText2" validator="#{someBean.someValidator}" value="item.model">
    <p:message id="someInputText2Msg" for="someInputText2" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Just to make sure: You also can set the *redisplay*-Attribute of *<p:message(s)>* to false. With this already rendered messages won't get displayed again. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I tried it, but it didn't work. Sorry, but it seems that you didn't understand my question. What I meant was that there is some inputText repeated for each separate item (object) in the dataTable. For instance the id of inputText for the first item will be "someDataTable:0:someInputText", for the second "someDataTable:1:someInputText" etc. The inputText component is just repeated for every item (object). My problem is that if for one item the inputText passes validation, and for the another does not, the validation message is shown for both inputTexts.

Comment: If you observe the clientIds someDataTable:0:someInputText and someDataTable:1:someInputText. someDataTable is the id of the datatable, followed by the rowindex and then someInputText which is the id of your inputText. You are using same Ids for inputText, you need to have unique ids for the inputText for each row then refer it by the for attribute making it to show message only for that particular inputText.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your creation of new FacesMessage to use component.getClientId() rather than "error: ".

That is:

```
if(someCondition) {
    throw new ValidatorException(
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, component.getClientId(), "validation failed"));
  }
```

Comment: Please see my question in the comment for your original question and respond if the following doesnt solve your issue